HttpContext.SignInAsync is not working properly or authentication happened in delayed
I have developed a .net 6 asp.net core web application. There, I have used HttpContext.SignInAsync method to authenticate. My codes are as below:
In program.cs:
builder.Services
.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(
    options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "cookie name";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        options.SlidingExpiration = false;
    });

Auth middleware registration:
.UseAuthentication()
.UseAuthorization()

Then in my login controller:
var claims = AssertPermissionClaims(user);
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, 
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new 
ClaimsPrincipal(identity));

//AssertPermissionClaims method
private static Claim[]? AssertPermissionClaims(AppUser user)
{
    var claims = new[] {
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user?.UserName ?? ""),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user?.RoleName ?? ""),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, user==null || 
     user.UserId==null?"":user.UserId.ToString())
  };
  return claims;
}

After this call I am redirecting to home page. And from HomeController when I am calling
User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated 

or
HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.UserData)?.Value

I am getting false or NULL. But if I reload the page few times in same home page, then it will get authenticated. I am in a confusion what is actually going on here? Is the authenticate process taking time? Or there is issue with my implementation?
Looking for an answer. Thanks.
Update: The issue is only happening to production server, dev server, it is working fine. Tried with custom SessionStore implementation as well. Same happening.

Hi, I tried your code in my side which worked well in my side, could you please provide a minimal sample for investigating the issue?
